# Hexedit of ASCII in exe not changing in app

Tags: python, exe, hex-editors

I am trying to modify an exe (of mine) with a hex editor.  It was originally written in Python using wx and turned into an exe via py2exe.  I lost the source code (ugh) and need to change one of the items in a dropdown menu.  It's a simple one character change, from a "6" to a "9". (Makes me think of Jimi Hendrix)

I have used several hex editors, and I can find the string and make the change and save the file.  However, when I open the modified exe, the drop down entry has not changed.  I can verify that the exe is different by opening it in the hex editor again and checking, and the string is set to the new value I need.  It just doesn't display that way when running the app.

I obviously don't play with hex editors (or hex, for that matter) much.  What am I missing?  TIA.

Comment: You're changing it in the wrong place. There is some other place where it is set, possibly multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this next to impossible to do this way, since there could be thousands of characters like this in the exe.  You'd probably be better off first searching for a less common item in your dropdown to give you a better chance of finding the "area" where it may be occurring.  Then do a more localized search nearby for the "6".  Even then, there's no guarantee these dropdown items will be located near each other in the executable (but I think it likely).

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I am searching by a larger string that returns only one match, then only changing the "6".  ie.  I will search for this: "Unique string 6", and then only change that 6.

Comment: ...and you're basically replacing 0x36 with 0x39 within that string, right?

Comment: Yes.  In the hex side, just changing the 36 to 39 and saving the file out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure the string is actually in the .exe file, and not in the library.zip file? If the string is in library.zip you will have a much easier time. According to the py2exe FAQ ( http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ ) your entry script will be byte-compiled and embedded as a resource in the .exe, while the other Python modules it imports will be in the library.zip file.

Assuming the string *is* in your entry script, the byte-compilation process (which I believe uses the marshal module) should leave the actual content of the string as ASCII or UTF-8. Is the string you're searching for longer than the "6" character you are searching for? I think it's likely you are just changing the wrong string (or indeed something that isn't even part of a string, which could be very bad). If you're pretty sure that it looks right (i.e. the string is at least 5 or 6 characters long and very distinctive), could it be that it just occurs multiple times in the file and you've changed the wrong instance?

If you want to go further, you could get a Windows resource editor and extract the resources from the .exe to recover the .pyo file, then use the marshal and dis modules to convert the bytecode back into Python opcodes and literals. That might give you a better idea of what strings are in the file:

http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html

Comment: There is no library.zip file.  I think I compiled it as a single file executable.  Yes the string is longer.  Lets say its 'Dropdown Item 6'  I am searching the exe for that string and it is only returning one match.  That's the string that I am changing, and it's not changing in the app.  uggh